# does PLINQ preserve the original order in a sequence?

Tags: c#, plinq

Is PLINQ guaranteed to return query results in the order of the original sequence being operated on, even if results are produced in parallel?  For instance:

```
new List<String>(){"a", "b", "c", "d"}.asParallel().Select(str => str + "a").asSequential().ToList().ForEach(str => Console.Write(str + ", ");
```

will the result always be "aa, ba, ca, da, "?

Comment: What's the point of using PLINQ with 4 items?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use `AsOrdered()`to preserve the order:

```
        new List<String>(){"a", "b", "c", "d"}
            .AsParallel()
            .AsOrdered()
            .Select(str => str + "a")
            .AsSequential()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(str => Console.Write(str + ", "));
```

Also check out this: [How to: Control Ordering in a PLINQ Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460719.aspx)